# Tar 100 Directories within Current Directory

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I am attempting to tar 100 directories within a certain directory to a tar file, but I do not want to add more than 100 of these directories to the file. For example, the current structure of the directories is like so

```
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/001/00000010/s01_2012_03_01
```

Each of these directories has a different number of files in it, and I would like these to be included in the tar as well. What I would like it to do is tar 100 directories with different `../00000010/..` portions of the path. In the end, it might end up creating a tar file with the following structure:

```
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/001/00000010/s01_2012_03_01/file.txt
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/001/00000010/s01_2012_03_01/file2.txt
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/001/00000010/s02_2012_03_01/file.txt
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/001/00000015/s01_2012_03_01/file.txt
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/004/00000100/s01_2012_03_01/file.txt
```

Consider the `00000010` portion of the path the directory that represents a "patient". All of the patient's files under his/her directory should be included in the tar. There should be 100 different patients tarred to the file, so if the first patient was `00000001` and the hundredth patient was `00000100`, the structure might look something like this.

```
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/001/00000001/s01_2012_03_01/file.txt
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/001/00000001/s01_2012_03_01/file2.txt
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/001/00000001/s02_2012_03_01/file.txt
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/001/00000002/s01_2012_03_01/file.txt
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/004/00000003/s01_2012_03_01/file.txt
...
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/001/00000100/s01_2012_03_01/file.txt
.../v0.0/category_name/edf/004/00000100/s02_2012_03_01/file.txt
```

This is just an example, and the patient directories will not be numbered in this exact way.

Comment: do you want to tar only the first 100 dirs?

Comment: You want 100 *unique* path components in that location? Or up to 100 files with the *same* path component in that location? Do you care *which* 100 entries you get if there are more than 100? Does it matter that some of those directories have a component of `001` and some have a component of `004`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have fixed this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood your question correctly, you can do it this way:

```
find . -type d | head -100 | tar czvf dirs.tgz -T -
```

Answer (score 0):

Create list of patient directories:

```
find -maxdepth 1 . -type d > dirs
```

Split into chunks of 100:

```
split -l 100 -d dirs chunk.
```

Archive directories in each chunk:

```
for f in chunk.* ; do tar -czvf ${f##chunk.}.tar.gz `cat $f` ; done
```

You will end up with archives called `00.tar.gz`, `01.tar.gz`, ... each containing 100 directories